# Lottery number generator with anonymous fuction as parent

Tags: javascript, html

Im kinda stuck here, i've made a program that calls a function twice. Within this program i have a for loop that makes random numbers up to 34, and a while loop that makes the program print 7 of these random numbers like in a lottery. I have gotten it to work, but want to either replace the while loop or make it more compact.

Like i mentioned I made a function for generating a random value beteen 1 and 34. This function is inside an anonymous function, connected to a button in the body element. I know I dont need to use an anonymous function, but I dont want to remove it since its part of an exercise. i've gotten this program to work, and it prints to paragraps with the function, one for winner numbers, and one for the users numbers.

```
   var navnLos = function(){

        var arrRightNumbers=rndNumb(7);
        var arrYourNumbers=rndNumb(7);
        var para=document.getElementById("vinnerRekke");
        var para2=document.getElementById("dinRekke");

        function rndNumb(x){
            var Numb=[];
            for(let i=0;i<x;i++){
                var rndoNumb=Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1;
                rndoNumb=Number(rndoNumb);

                while
                (rndoNumb===Numb[0]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[1]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[2]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[3]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[4]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[5]||
                 rndoNumb===Numb[6]){
                    rndoNumb=Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1;
                }
                Numb.push(rndoNumb);
            }
            return Numb;
        }
        para.innerHTML="Winner numbers: " + arrRightNumbers;
        para2.innerHTML="your numbers: " + arrYourNumbers;
    }
```

i've got the results I want, but I want to try and make the code more compact, without removing the anon function as parent. Specifically I want to rewrite the while loop, so it does not look as messy. and I also would love for a suggestion on a secondary function that compares the two paragrafs whith numbers, and prints how many of the numbers are the same.

Comment: The obvious improvement is to get rid of all the individual tests with `while ( Numb.includes(rndNumb )){ ... }`

Comment: @MarkMeyer You mean rnd**o**Numb. OP's naming is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is a natural fit when you want a collection with no duplicates. You can draw 7 numbers and put them in the set. If there are duplicates, they won't be in the set and it will then be smaller than your target size.

For example:

```js
function navnLos(){

  let arrRightNumbers=rndNumb(7);
  let arrYourNumbers=rndNumb(7);

  function rndNumb(x){
      let Numb = new Set(Array.from({length: 7}, () => Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1));
      while (Numb.size < 7){
          Numb.add(Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1);
      }
      return [...Numb];
  }
  console.log("Winner numbers: " + arrRightNumbers);
  console.log("your numbers: " + arrYourNumbers)
  console.log("winning picks:", countSame(arrRightNumbers, arrYourNumbers) )
}

navnLos()

function countSame(arr1, arr2){
  return arr1.reduce((sum, item) => sum + arr2.includes(item), 0)
}
```

Comment: this looks really good, but if i may ask, do you have a suggestion to an additional function that prints how many of the values in the two arrays is the same, in a third paragraph?

Comment: @ØyvindOlsen sure, see the edit — it uses `reduce()` to count how many from one array are in the other.

Comment: i tried it out, looks like it looks at it as the same number if only one of the numbers is in each value like this: Winning numbers: 15,1,31,5,12,14,25 - your numbers: 32,12,4,34,10,14,29 -  winning picks: 2

Comment: @ØyvindOlsen in that example 14 and 12 are in both groups. So there are two winning picks. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: oh, holy, its just me that have to learn to read closer, you nailed it. thank you so much, im gonna go get me some new glasses.

Comment: may i ask you another question? if i were to make this program automatic, and then count how many times the program would run until both arrays displayed the same numbers, how would i go about it?

Comment: I think you would make `navnLos` return the count of winning numbers. Then call it in a loop while you increased the counter until the count is what you want. It will be faster if you leave the picks as sets and use `.has()` rather than `includes()`. I was able to get a winning pick after a few million tries.

Comment: i think i have a grasp on what you're suggesting, but im stuck on how to implement it, im not very well versed on automating programs yet, is it possible for you to show a little, if its not too much trouble?

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more function for generating a new number getNewNumber().

It takes a current array and check a new number.

The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

if there is the same number in array getNewNumber() will call itself once more

```
var navnLos = function(){

    var arrRightNumbers=rndNumb(7);
    var arrYourNumbers=rndNumb(7);
    var para=document.getElementById("vinnerRekke");
    var para2=document.getElementById("dinRekke");

    function getNewNumber(currentArr) {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1; // Math.floor round a number downward to its nearest integer
        return currentArr.indexOf(num) === -1 ? num : getNewNumber(currentArr);
    }

    function rndNumb(x){
        var Numb=[];
        for(let i=0;i<x;i++){
            Numb.push(getNewNumber(Numb));
        }
        return Numb;
    }
    para.innerHTML="Winner numbers: " + arrRightNumbers;
    para2.innerHTML="your numbers: " + arrYourNumbers;
}
```

Comment: `inclides` is more suitable in this case as Mark Meyer mentioned in the comments. No need for ternary when boolean is returned

Comment: there are several ways to solve this. Includes is ok, but IE doesn't support includes :)
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which only allows unique values and keep adding until the set's `size` matches total expected

```js
function rndNumb(x){
  const numSet = new Set();
  while(numSet.size < x){
     numSet.add(Math.floor(Math.random()*34)+1)
  }
  return Array.from(numSet);
}

console.log(rndNumb(7))
```